# Reactive Extensions, locks and threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

I'm using reactive extensions to work with a wpf ui, basically I have a textbox I need to both do sampling and throttling (doing some stuff continously while typing and some stuff when stopped typing) on small timespans (200-300 ms)

The problem is that it's somewhat unpredictable and sometimes triggers throttle immediately, this might be because the TextUpdated event didnt make it to the observable or something with the observable itself.  I'm also doing some locking that might interfer but that's typically done through new Tasks and not on the UI thread. I also have a sneaking suspicion that debugging might affect the behavior since it seems to trigger more "incorrectly" when I set breakpoints

Since the observable is created on the UI thread I assume (perhaps mistakenly) it's timer's or whatever it uses underneath is also on that thread, might it be a good idea to create a a new thread for creating the observables so it's not interfered by  UI overhead and potential locking? How do I set up such a thread in the best way, I guess a empty while-loop at the end of it might not be such a good idea :)

How does Throttle, Sample work and reactive extensions in relationship with threads work under the hood anyway?

**EDIT**

Seems the problem was the way I was testing it :P If you hold down a key it seems there's a 500 ms delay before it starts repeating, if you just bang on the keys it works fine. Sigh

Comment: Are you heavily using the ThreadPool (other than your implicit use through Sample/Throttle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Sample` and `Throttle` use `Scheduler.ThreadPool` for their timings so I high doubt that's the problem.

I recommend adding some logging to the code to find out where the bottleneck is:

```
sourceEvents.LogInterval("Source")
    .Throttle(throttleTimeSpan).LogInterval("Throttled")
    .Sample(sampleTimeSpan).LogInterval("Sample")
    .Subscribe();
```

Here is the definition of `LogInterval`:

```
public static class ObservableEx
{
    public static IObservable<TSource> LogInterval(
        this IObservable<TSource> source, string message)
    {
        return source
            .TimeInterval()
            .Do(x => Debug.WriteLine("{0} :: {1} ({2})", 
                message, x.Value, x.Interval.TotalMilliseconds);
            .RemoveTimeInteval();
    }
}
```

If the bottleneck is the throttle/sample, it probably means you are saturating the ThreadPool elsewhere. If that is the case, and the performance of these throttles is important, you might consider creating a dedicated thread+dispatcher and using a custom `DistpatcherScheduler` for the Throttle/Sample. Alternatively, there might be a nicer TPL way of solving it.

Comment: The problem is that a simplified version that would be just a wpf textbox and two different reactive extensions hooked up to it's textchanged observable works  well. It's when the load of the app increases it seems the problems starts. Can it be since I'm using parallel extensions as well I might have saturated the threadpool or something for the reactive extensions?

Comment: See updated to track down the bottleneck. Yes, if you are making heavy use of the ThreadPool, there may simply not be enough resources available.